# Keeping cloned partition as bootable backup

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd, backup, disk-cloning

I'll try to keep it short,

I want to clone my current Windows 7 Install from an HDD
[80GB System (C:) and 1,7TB Data (D:)]  to an SSD.
The last SSD I installed unfortunately broke after only a few months.
So this time I'd like to keep my current install as an bootable backup, while mainly running windows from the SSD.

What would be the best way to set up something like this?
Would cloning Windows to another drive without removing the old one cause any issues, e.g. drive letters etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are C: and D: partitions of the same drive, and you're cloning just C:?

Comment: Yes, that's the plan.